# How to get span text with selenium?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

```html
<p id="line1" class=""><span class="bot">So you have short term memory?</span><span id="snipTextIcon" class="yellow" style="opacity: 1;"></span></p>
```

**I wanna get this text:** `So you have short term memory?`

**Here is my code :**

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js');
const {Options} = require('./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js');
(async function() {
  let driver;
  try {
    driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(
            new Options().setMobileEmulation({deviceName: 'Nexus 5X'}))
        .build();
    await driver.get('https://www.cleverbot.com/');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('stimulus')).sendKeys('naber', Key.RETURN);

    const waitFind = (locator) => {
        return driver.findElement(async () => {
            await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(locator));
            return driver.findElement(locator);
        });
    }

    let a = await driver.findElement(By.id('line1')).getText();
    console.log(a);
    await waitFind(By.id('line1'), 5000)
    //await waitFind(By.id('snipTextIcon'), 5000);
  } finally {
    await driver && driver.quit();
  }
})().then(_ => console.log('SUCCESS'), err => console.error('ERROR: ' + err));
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\pyramid\OneDrive\Masaüstü\deneme> node app

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52265/devtools/browser/*******

SUCCESS
```

I didn't find too much documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

The text element `So you have short term memory?` is present inside Span tag.Use following xpath to get the text.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//span[@class="bot"]')).getText()
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//p[@id="line1"]//span[@class="bot"]')).getText()
```

Comment: ```PS C:\Users\pyramid\OneDrive\Masaüstü\deneme> node app

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54264/devtools/browser/**********
SUCCESS``` no output on console

Comment: @PyramidSeo : can you try that `driver.findElement(By.xpath('//span[@class="bot"]')).getAttribute("textContent")`

Comment: Can you provided the updated code what you have tried.If the element present in DOM it should work.

Comment: I believe you have provided enough wait to load the element.

Comment: ```let a = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//p[@id="line1"]//span[@class="bot"]')).getText();``` then console.log(a); but no output

Comment: I have checked on the webpage  what I observe that xpath is fine.However page is loading once you click enter and selenium unable to sync that if you provide some `Thread.sleep(2000)` before that line it will work. I have tested on python programming.it will work on your case as well.

Comment: Oh okay. ```var sleep = require('sleep');``` then ```let a = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//p[@id="line1"]//span[@class="bot"]'), 2000).getText();
    sleep.sleep(10);``` output : ```PS C:\Users\pyramid\OneDrive\Masaüstü\deneme> node app

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63842/devtools/browser/
İyiyim sen.
SUCCESS``` Now working

Comment: you need to sleep before the element. `var sleep = require('sleep');
sleep.sleep(10);
let a = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//p[@id="line1"]//span[@class="bot"]'), 2000).getText(); `

Comment: @PyramidSeo : If it resolve your problem please accept the answer by clicking on hollow under down vote button.Thanks